# Parse copied data from Excel using AutoHotkey

Tags: array, autohotkey

#### Code Objective

I'm writing an AutoHotkey script which takes in department data copied to the clipboard from a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet. It then uses this data to auto-fill forums in the web-app Kronos Workforce Central.

#### Source Data

When data is copied from Microsoft Excel, each cell in a row is stored in the clipboard as strings delimited by tabs `\t`, with each row separated by newlines `\r\n`.

```
DeptID     Job Name           Abbreviation     Service Line  
0368       Administrator      ADMIN            OPS
3945       Programmer         PRGRM            NON NRSG
4596       Software Engineer  SFTWRE-ENG       NON NRSG
```

#### Current Method

Currently, I'm parsing this copied-data by splitting the data into an array of rows with `StrSplit()`, then using a second `StrSplit()` inside a for-loop to parse my data.

```
; Autofill data from clipboard
#d::
   addLocationsWindow := "Add Locations"
   WinActivate, %addLocationsWindow%        ; Window MUST be active

   rowArray := StrSplit(Clipboard, "`r`n")  ; Split copied rows from Excel by newlines
   for index, row in rowArray {
      tempArray := StrSplit(row, "`t")      ; Split each row by tabs
      deptID := tempArray[1]
      jobName := tempArray[2]

      If (deptID == "")                     ; skip empty cells
         continue

      IfWinNotActive(addLocationsWindow)  ; check for active window
      {
         MsgBox '%addLocationsWindow%' window not found. Stopping script...
         Exit, 1
      }

      ; DoStuff(jobName, deptDisplayName, index)
   }
Return
```

#### The Issue

My method of string parsing feels hacky and unintuitive. It means I can only manipulate a single row at a time, as each each row's data is only split temporarily. I would need to re-run the costly `StrSplit()` to access data from a row again.

In Java, I could store my Excel data in a single 2D array. Unfortunately, arrays are a bit tricky to use in AutoHotkey, which is why my current code is a bit messy.

Answer (score 2):

*I realize this is an older question, but hopefully, this will help a future asker, if not the original asker.*

I agree with your assessment of using `StrSplit()` and would recommend using a 2D array. This can be done using a nested parsing loop. Here is a working example of the data in your example (assuming the range was copied from Excel and not from your post):

```
f1::
aData := {} , nCt := 0 , clipboard := RegExReplace( clipboard , "`r" , "" )
Loop , Parse , clipboard , `n
{
    nCt++
    Loop , Parse , A_LoopField , `t
        aData[ nCt , A_Index ] := A_LoopField
}
Loop , % aData.Length()
    MsgBox , % aData[A_Index,1] . "`t" . aData[A_Index,2] . "`t" . aData[A_Index,3]
Return
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you. This is not an alternative solution, but rather addresses what OP mentions under "The Issue" (also, this is just an example of how to use a multidimensional array in AHK and not meant to be a replacement of any section of code). The portion of the code this address is where `StrSplit()` is used. The OP mentions the drawbacks of using `StrSplit()`, which I agree with and edited to make clearer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, and have an upvote!